# array as value for tar --exclude

Tags: shell, backup, tar, array

I want to write a little backup script, but I need to exclude some directories. So I decided to set all my excluded directories in a array like this.

```
exclude[0] = '/home/user/test1'
exclude[1] = '/home/user/test2'
exclude[2] = '/home/user/test3'
```

Is it possible to provide this array as a parameter for the tar command?

```
tar -zcvf $FILE $SOURCE --exclude=exclude
```

Comment: Did you try --exclude="${exclude[@]}" and is not working?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou may as well post that as an answer, it's almost certainly the problem. The OP doesn't know the right syntax for arrays.

Comment: Isn't better to use `--exclude-from` and create a file with your exclusions than dealing with arrays?

Comment: Yeah. Good Idea!
It's work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you could use `--exclude-from` switch to deal with multiple locations

```
tar --exclude-from=/home/user/exclude.txt -zcvf "$FILE" "$SOURCE"
```

And now, create a file with one regular expression on each line.

```
cat /home/user/exclude.txt

/home/user/test1
/home/user/test2
/home/user/test3
```

Comment: Good alternative. It would be interesting if this alternative could work with the array directly instead of having a separate file with exclusions...

Comment: But that is the point: To avoid arrays. I know that working with arrays could be a strong requisite of the envisioned OP solution. However, if that is something that could change, `--exclude-from` is a good enough feature of `tar` to handle this issue ;).

Comment: One limitation with that approach is you can't have patterns that contain newline characters (like for `--exclude=$'*\n*'` to exclude files with newlines in their name).

Comment: Mentally health people avoid newline character on filenames. LOL.

Comment: @nwildner Archiving files whose names were chosen by other people is common.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
exclude=(
  /home/user/test1
  /home/user/test2
  /home/user/test3
)
tar  --exclude=$^exclude -zcvf $FILE $SOURCE
```

The `$^exclude` syntax makes the above expand to

```
tar  --exclude=/home/user/test1 --exclude=/home/user/test2 \
     --exclude=/home/user/test3 -zcvf the-file the-source
```

The `rc`, `es` and `fish` shells do that kind of processing with arrays by default, so in those shells you can do:

```
tar  --exclude=$exclude -zcvf $FILE $SOURCE
```

(use `set exclude /home/user/test1 /home/user/test2 /home/user/test3` to define the array in `fish`).

Answer (score 2):

Each parameter to a command is a string. You can't pass an array to the `--exclude` option. You need to pass multiple `--exclude` options, or use another method such as [`--exclude-from`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338860). [A few shells have a neat way to interpolate an array with a prefix added to each element](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338866), but most (sh, bash, ksh, …) don't.

One thing that works in all shells is to build the command line gradually.

```
set -- tar -zcvf "$FILE" 
set -- "$@" --exclude='/home/user/test1'
set -- "$@" --exclude='/home/user/test2'
set -- "$@" --exclude='/home/user/test3'
"$@" "$SOURCE"
```

If you're using bash or ksh and you have an array of patterns to exclude, you can build the command line by iterating over the array.

```
exclude=('/home/user/test1' '/home/user/test2' '/home/user/test3')
exclude_options=()
for x in "${exclude[@]}"; do
  exclude_options+=(--exclude="$x")
done
tar -zcvf "$FILE" "${exclude_options[@]}" "$SOURCE"
```

Older versions of ksh and bash lack the `+=` operator so they require `exclude_options=("${exclude_options[@]}" --exclude="$x")` as the loop body.

Instead of building a separate array for the exclude options, you can build the command line directly, either in a named array variable or in the array of positional parameters.

```
exclude=('/home/user/test1' '/home/user/test2' '/home/user/test3')
set -- tar -zcvf "$FILE"
for x in "${exclude[@]}"; do
  set -- "$@" --exclude="$x"
done
 "$@" "$SOURCE"
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is like this:

```
gv@debi64:$ ls -l *.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 56376 Jan 20 12:40 bashtest.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2682 Dec 14 17:58 cpu.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3661 Dec 14 17:58 greptest.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1215 Dec 14 17:58 iconlist.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22096 Jan 20 11:22 inst.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   141 Jan 18 09:21 oneshot.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   154 Dec 27 17:48 remove.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2393 Dec 14 17:58 twoscreens.sh

$ ex[0]='--exclude=cpu.sh'
$ ex[1]='--exclude=inst.sh'
$ tar "${ex[@]}" -cvf backup.tar *.sh
bashtest.sh
greptest.sh
iconlist.sh
oneshot.sh
remove.sh
twoscreens.sh
```

As you can see the files cpu.sh and inst.sh are omited by the archive.

Similarly you could build your array like this :

```
exclude[0]='--exclude=/home/user/test1'
exclude[1]='--exclude=/home/user/test2'
exclude[2]='--exclude=/home/user/test3'
```

As an alternative, bellow method also worked for me without the need to store in array elements "--exclude" in front.

```
$ ex[0]='cpu.sh'
$ ex[1]='inst.sh'
$ IFS=,
$ excluded=$(eval echo "--exclude="{"${ex[*]}"})
$ unset IFS
$ tar "$excluded" -cvf backup.tar *.sh
```

The trick here is the second line that will add in front of each array element the word `--excluded=` using brace expansion without requiring a loop into array elements.
In  order brace expansion to work, array elements must be separated by comma and this is ensured by changing IFS to comma.

```
$ echo "$excluded"
--exclude=cpu.sh --exclude=inst.sh
```

Comment: @ToyRobotic Answer updated. You should be ok now.

Comment: @Gilles It happened that your edits to be in the same time with my edits in answer. As a result your edits are lost. I have keep some of your edits as shown in history, but if you can please have a look and re-edit if necessary.

Comment: There's too much for me to edit. Why do you include this part at the beginning with a solution that doesn't work (except in zsh with the right option set, but Stéphane has posted a zsh answer that's simpler and doesn't require this option)? The second solution could almost work but it's missing the array declaraion and the assignment syntax is wrong. The third solution can work but it breaks dangerously on file names containing special characters. Don't use `eval` unless you understand what you're doing and read http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346

Comment: @Gilles Ok , i re-edited. About eval i tried this method and without eval i was not capable to perform a correct brace expansion for the alternative solution. About array declaration, i did some tests with file names containing spaces or * inside and come correctly without any strange effects. I saw that you edit my post in first place and i was happy about that since i respect your experience. But your last comment makes me feel uncomfortable here.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rsync -avz -e "ssh -i your-pem-key.pem" --exclude-from=folder-name-files/exclude.txt folder-name-files/ ubuntu@13.235.138.16:folder-files/
```

In the file `exclude.txt` you should mention all ignored files like:

```
/assets
.gitignore
exclude.txt
```

Comment: This does not seem to be related to the current question, which is about exluding files when creating a `tar` archive.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# below works for me

EXCLUDIRS='
--exclude='*/config/excludesomedirectoryhere/*'
--exclude='*/config/anotherone/*'
'
tar cvpzf $DIRECTORY_BAK_DAILY${NAME} $EXCLUDIRS $DIRECTORY_BAKD
```

Comment: The question specifically asks about arrays; your answer doesn’t address that.

Comment: Stephen - An yet, it does exactly what the question specifically wants to accomplish, without use of an external file as some of the answers suggest.